# Invalid input code for Rock Paper Scissors game does not accept good inputs

Tags: c

I am currently working on a Rock Paper Scissors game for my class and I was wondering why when I try to validate the user input to make sure that the user entered either r, p, or s, regardless of whether or not I inputted a good input, it always runs the code where the user entered bad input, which does not allow the game to progress any further. Here is some code so you can see the problem:

```
char playerOneChoice() {
char playerOneInput;
printf("Player-1, please enter your choice of <r>ock, <p>aper, or <s>cissors:\n");
playerOneInput = getchar();

while (playerOneInput != 'r' || playerOneInput != 'R' || playerOneInput != 'p' || playerOneInput != 'P' || playerOneInput != 's' || playerOneInput != 'S') {
        printf("Invalid choice\n");
        clearKeyboardBuffer();
        playerOneChoice();
    }

    return playerOneInput;
}
```

I have also tried to use scanf to grab the users input from the keyboard, however regardless of what I input, the program begins to run the while loop.

Comment: Your `while` condition is always true. Think about what it means: "Continue the loop if `playerOneInput` is not `'r'` or if `playerOneInput` is not `'R'` or if `playerOneInput` it not `'p'` or if [...]". If you plug in e.g. `'p'` into this condition, is it not going to continue, as you expect?

Answer (score 2):

You have to put a `&&` (and) instead of `||` (or) in the test of while.

The input is invalid if it’s not an r **and** not a p **and** not a s.